# Can I make my own foil faced insulation?

Tags: insulation, attic

I come across this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6F_IkZJ8NOY) where they talk about the product called SilverGlo.

I'd like to add this insulation into my attic on my own but I am unable to find a seller. I found a similar product in home depot but it's only 1 inch thick or it is a bare styrofoam without the both sided aluminum foil barrier. I need at least 3 inches and both sided radiant barrier. All I can find are the contractors who can do it for me. I'd like to save money and do it myself since it doesn't seem to be a rocket science.

Is it possible to use bare styrofoam and wrap it into radiant barrier foil somehow to make it both sided rigid foam?

[image]

Comment: SilverGlo is just a specific brand of foil faced polyiso insulation panel. It looks different because they put graphite in it.  *Any* foil faced polyiso panel with a similar R value will do the same thing.

Comment: @Comintern, right, but where do I get these rigid foam panels treated with the foil and the thickness of the panel in the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a close look at most the so called "foil" lined rigid foam boards.  You'll notice they are nothing more than aluminum painted paper.  For all I know, the silver looking stuff might just be silver paint.  One thing for sure, it's not aluminum foil - and THAT is what you need.  Silver painted plastic or foam doesn't do crap. So, to answer your question, "yes" you would have a more effective product buying the rigid foam and then wrapping it with sheets of aluminum foil.  And, the way to buy aluminum foil on the cheap is to get it from restaurant supply companies.  Their foil comes in wider and longer rolls (often a slightly thicker foil sheet than what is in supermarkets) and it costs way less per foot than buying it from a supermarket.  That's what I did.  Good luck!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Nice answer; keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 2):

Like @keshlam said, a quick search online will tell you what you need to know...

Seems like SilverGlo is a product designed by the Dr. Energy Saver company, which also was the company behind the video you saw. Apparently, this product is simply rigid foam board of the Expanded Polystyrene variety (EPS), covered with their radiant barrier facing. EPS actually has the lowest R-value of all the foam board types.

See: [Dr. Energy Saver Rigid Foam Wall Insulation](http://www.drenergysaver.com/insulation/wall-insulation/rigid-foam-wall-insulation.html)

If you want something with higher R-value, try using one of the other foam board types, like polyisocyanurate or Extruded Polystyrene (XPS). Polyisocyanurate usually comes faced with foil on both sides. You can easily find both at big box stores in a variety of thicknesses.

As for 3" thickness, they might not carry, but you can always stack and glue/mechanically fasten smaller thicknesses up to the thickness you require.

I would also check local distributors/contractor oriented stores that sell to consumers. They may have better pricing and also delivery services. From personal experience, a 4ft by 8ft standard sheet of rigid foam board does not fit inside the small SUVs (RAV4/CRV etc) they make nowadays...

Comment: Now I'm actually thinking about cellulose or AttiCa but thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: With regards to pricing, the same goes for cellulose/blown in fiberglass. I've been doing a lot of research here in the northeast and I've been able to find cheaper prices from distributors and/or local hardware stores supplied by big suppliers. (i.e., ever heard of DoItBest.com?)

Comment: no, what is your suggestion?

Comment: Simply that calling around and researching is a good idea...
as for the site I suggested, when you search for locations, you find that they supply a lot of local hardware stores, not named doitbest, but usually more like John Doe's Hardware store or Town Name Hardware...

Comment: EPS Rigid Insulation is musch more sustainable than the XPS or the Polycyanurate. The problm with these types is that THEY LOSE R VALUE OVER TIME.
EPS does not.